# Programmatic soundtrack composing

Tags: java, c++, audio-recording

I am looking for a library, preferably written in C/C++, but Java is also fine, where I can programmatically compose a sound track from many different sound files loaded in runtime with ability to transcode and save to different audio formats. I have found Juce project, but I see it has GUI layer. I need the library 100% code and  open source.